# Cursor position wrong in Firefox input element (searchbox)

Tags: firefox, input, cursor, css

I'm having trouble with the cursor in a searchbox that displays too far left in Firefox, whereas it looks fine in Chrome and Safari.  The CSS uses [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to display a borderradius where possible, so the issue doesn't concern IE which is served a plain square box.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="/search-results/" id="search" role="search">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search this site here" name="q" results=5 id="q" autocomplete="off" size="31"/>
</form>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
```

to display the placeholder and

```
.borderradius #search input#q {
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

.no-borderradius #search input#q {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    font: inherit;
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 8px
}
```

to style the box.

I also added this:

```
/* Remove default input type="search styling */
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* You could also use none */
}
```

(which I saw in [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2011/08/16/html5-forms-input-types-attributes-and-new-elements-demos-tips-and-tricks/)) which has the effect of removing the 'enforced' styling of the Webkit search box—meaning it can then be made to render consistently in Mozilla with the right styling.

Adding the `results=5`attribute in the input tag, although it doesn't currently validate, displays a magnifying glass in Webkit.

The above code can also be checked online on [my site](http://donaldjenkins.com/).

The search box displays as follows:

**Safari**

[image: Safari]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

Firefox doesn't display the magnifying glass, but that's fine.  On the other hand, while adjusting the margin and/or padding on the box can correct the wrong (too far left) Firefox cursor display, it necessarily does so at the (unacceptable) cost of pushing it too far right in Webkit browsers.  And I haven't found a way of targeting just Mozilla in this instance.  Any suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be fair, Firefox isn't displaying the *wrong* cursor position. If you remove the invalid `results` attribute, you will see the cursor position is in the same place in webkit.

I am not sure what padding/margins you have tried, but the padding below looked fine in both browsers. The `box-sizing:` properties are used so that the input acts the same way in all browsers and doesn't make the box bigger with the extra padding.

```
.borderradius #search input#q{
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: This solution works without, crucially, lengthening the box [see screenshot here: http://i.via.dj/COY2 ]—although I've added `-moz-appearance: none;` and `-webkit-appearance: none;`taken from Ed-M's solution, which makes the search boxes entirely identical in all three browsers.

Comment: UPDATED: I actually changed the padding to 4px, because 6px would overlap slightly with the magnifying glass in Safari...

Answer (score 1):

This is complex - it seems to me that we've some way to go before native styling of the new form elements works well cross-browser. I have put together [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/SqYvY/) which shows the code necessary to display your search input properly in both webkit browsers and Firefox.

[This article by Trent Walton](http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/) describes the various properties that affect the appearance of search inputs, and the always brilliant CSS Tricks [also has some useful information](http://css-tricks.com/7261-webkit-html5-search-inputs/).

Basically, I've over-ruled the browser's native styling using this code:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

I've then used the [-moz-padding-start property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-padding-start) (who knew?) to add some left padding only for Firefox.

So, although that works, it is far from ideal having to jump through those hoops. A note on @tw16's answer: `-moz-box-sizing` is currently used by even the most recent version of Firefox, but is likely to be replaced by the non-prefixed version in future, which will potentially break that solution. To be fair, `-moz-padding-start` will presumably be similarly replaced at some point in the future, though the [CSS Writing Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/) seems more obscure (to me at least).

Comment: Thanks.  The CSS Tricks article actually was what actually what set me wanting to style the box like this—taking it the other way round, styling it *like* a Webkit search box rather than the other way round.  I forgot to mention in the question that I'd removed the default Webkit styling by using `/* Remove default input type="search styling */
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* You could also use none */
}`which achieves the same result as the last selector in your fiddle (I think).  I've edited the question to make this clear.  Thanks for your solution!

Comment: One residual issue, though, is that the extra padding lengthens the search box in due proportion [see screenshot here:  http://i.via.dj/CORc ]—so ultimately, one's brought back to the -moz-box-sizing solution, unless there's a way of specifying a max-width that would apply in all browsers regardless of padding.